# Stubbing/mocking global constants in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a gem, which has a method which acts differently depending on the Rails.env:

```
def self.env
  if defined?(Rails)
    Rails.env
  elsif ...
```

And now I'd like to write a spec, which tests this code path. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
Kernel.const_set(:Rails, nil)
Rails.should_receive(:env).and_return('production')
...
```

And it's ok, just feels ugly. Another way is to declare this in `spec_helper`:

```
module Rails; end
```

And it works as well. But maybe there is a better way? Ideally this should work:

```
rails = double('Rails')
rails.should_receive(:env).and_return('production')
```

But, well, it does not. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the various tweets about this, switching on constants is *generally* a bad idea because it makes things a bit of a challenge to test and you have to change the state of constants in order to do so (which makes them a little less than constant). That said, if you're writing a plugin that has to behave differently depending on the environment in which it's loaded, you're going to have to test on the existence of `Rails`, `Merb`, etc to somewhere, even if it's not in this particular part of the code. Wherever it is, you want to keep it isolated so that decision happens only once. Something like `MyPlugin::env`. Now you can safely stub that method in most places, and then spec that method by stubbing constants.

As to how to stub the constants, your example doesn't look quite right. The code is asking if `defined?(Rails)`, but `Kernel.const_set(:Rails, nil)` doesn't undefine the constant, it just sets its value to `nil`. What you want is something like this (disclaimer - this is off the top of my head, untested, not even run, may contain syntax errors, and is not well factored):

```
def without_const(const)
  if Object.const_defined?(const)
    begin
      @const = const
      Object.send(:remove_const, const)
      yield
    ensure
      Object.const_set(const, @const)
    end
  else
    yield
  end
end

def with_stub_const(const, value)
  if Object.const_defined?(const)
    begin
      @const = const
      Object.const_set(const, value)
      yield
    ensure
      Object.const_set(const, @const)
    end
  else
    begin
      Object.const_set(const, value)
      yield
    ensure
      Object.send(:remove_const, const)
    end
  end
end

describe "..." do
  it "does x if Rails is defined" do
    rails = double('Rails', :env => {:stuff_i => 'need'})
    with_stub_const(:Rails, rails) do
      # ...
    end
  end

  it "does y if Rails is not defined" do
    without_const(:Rails) do
      # ....
    end
  end
end
```

I'll give some thought as to whether we should include this in rspec or not. It's one of those things that if we added people would use it as an excuse to rely on constants when they don't need to :)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I think I now understand this a whole lot better. Btw. using `Kernel.const_set(:Rails, nil)` makes is that `Rails` is defined (even though it's `nil`), just as you say (and I was aware of that). Shortly after writing this question I've made it `Kernel.const_set(:Rails, Module)`, so that it's not confusing. The solution to my problem is just maybe leaving `MyPlugin::env` method untested and all is well.

Comment: As of Rspec 2.11 you can now `stub_const("FOO", :bar)`

Answer (score 1):

To test the condition where Rails is defined

```
 mock_rails = mock(:env => mock)
 Kernel.stub(:Rails).and_return(mock_rails)
```

To test the condition where Rails is undefined I believe you should not have to do anything otherwise you would define Rails and then the if defined?(Rails) condition would be true again

Comment: Per David's comment - this is a hack, but it works, so I've upvoted your answer as well.

Comment: Hm... seems I haven't really checked this, but I cannot make it work: `mock_rails = mock(:env => mock)`, `Kernel.stub(:Rails).and_return(mock_rails)`, `::Rails.should_receive(:env).and_return('production')`

=> NameError: uninitialized constant Rails

Comment: The last line should be mock_rails.should_receive(:env).and_return('production')

Answer (score 1):

Modern way of stubbing global constants in RSpec involves using `stub_const`. Lets say you have a method using `Rails`, which you would like to test in an environment where `Rails` is not defined (a rubygem for example):

```
def MyClass
  def cache_value key, value
    Rails.cache.write key, value
  end
end
```

You can write a spec for this method like this:

```
it 'writes the value to the cache' do
  key = :key
  value = 'abc'

  cache = double 'cache'
  rails = double 'Rails', cache: cache

  stub_const('Rails', rails)

  expect(cache).to receive(:write).with(key, value)

  MyClass.new.cache_value key, value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7849835/457819) helped me out a lot. I modified it a little bit to handle multiple constants:

```
# Mock a constant within the passed block
# @example mock RAILS_ENV constant
#   it "does not allow links to be added in production environment" do
#     with_constants :RAILS_ENV => 'production' do
#       get :add, @nonexistent_link.url
#       response.should_not be_success
#     end
#   end
# @note adapted from:
#   * https://stackoverflow.com/a/7849835/457819
#   * http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=551
def with_constants(constants)
  @constants_to_restore = {}
  @constants_to_unset   = []

  constants.each do |name, val|
    if Object.const_defined?(name)
      @constants_to_restore[name] = Object.const_get(name)
    else
      @constants_to_unset << name
    end

    Object.const_set( name, val )
  end

  begin
    yield
  ensure
    @constants_to_restore.each do |name, val|
      Object.const_set( name, val )
    end

    @constants_to_unset.each do |name|
      Object.send(:remove_const, name)
    end
  end
end

def without_constants(constants)
  @constants_to_restore = {}

  constants.each do |name, val|
    if Object.const_defined?(name)
      @constants_to_restore[name] = Object.const_get(name)
    end

    Object.send(:remove_const, name)
  end

  begin
    yield
  ensure
    @constants_to_restore.each do |name, val|
      Object.const_set( name, val )
    end
  end
end
```